# Kirk and Spock friendship in Original Series

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos

The 2nd through 6th original Star Trek movies make a lot of reference to Kirk and Spock's friendship.

In particular Spock says, 'I am and always shall be your friend.'

I can't recall their friendship coming up so blatantly in the show. Sure they were convivial and seemed to enjoy their company.  But did either make direct reference to being friends with the other?  Did another Enterprise member ever  comment on their friendship? Or did they only realize they had become friends much later?

Particularly interested in Spock saying it.

I'm not looking for statements made for subterfuge, like when Kirk says 'This is my clearly Chinese friend' to Edith about Spock in 'City on Edge of Forever'

Comment: "But did either make direct reference to being friends with the other?" - I'm not sure what you're expecting here. At least to me, co-workers who I consider friends are still "co-workers" when I mention them toward other people, and I cannot imagine any situation in which I would directly tell someone something like "You're my friend!"

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Hi. They directly say they're friends in the movies, and I wanted to know if they did that in the episodes, what's wrong with that? Also, what purpose does your comment serve 17 hours after the accepted answer that verifies they **do** call each other friends on the show?

Comment: I was simply wondering why you would expect the friendship to be explicitly mentioned, and pointed out why I do not think such an explicit mention is necessarily bound to happen normally between people. This is, in particular, referring to your question "Or did they only realize they had become friends much later?", which implies that people who realize they are friends will invariably declare that friendship. Of course, nothing is wrong with just asking "if they did that in the episodes" :)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

There are direct references to their friendship in all of the forms you have described: statements by Kirk, statements by Spock, and statements by other crew members (McCoy in particular).

## *TOS* ["Journey to Babel"](http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/44.htm)

Kirk calling Spock his friend:

> **KIRK:** Spock is my best officer, and **my friend**.
>
> **AMANDA:** I'm glad he has such a friend. It hasn't been easy on Spock. Neither human nor Vulcan. At home nowhere except Starfleet.

## *TOS* ["Return to Tomorrow"](http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/51.htm)

McCoy commenting that Spock is Kirk's best friend:

> **McCOY:** Jim, the receptacles. Spock's consciousness was in one of them.
>
> **KIRK:** It was necessary.
>
> **McCOY:** What are you talking about? There is no Spock to return to his body. You've killed a loyal officer, **your best friend.**

## *TOS* ["Amok Time"](http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/34.htm)

McCoy commenting on Kirk and Spock being friends:

> **McCOY:** **These men are friends.** To force them to fight until one of them is killed —
>
> **T'PAU:** I can forgive such a display only once.

Kirk calling Spock his friend:

> **KIRK:** I can't let Spock die, can I, Bones? And he will if we go to Altair. I owe him my life a dozen times over. Isn't that worth a career? **He's my friend**.

Kirk emphasizes it again later in the episode:

> **KIRK:** Bones. He's my first officer and **my friend**. I disregarded Starfleet orders to bring him here.

Spock calling both Kirk and McCoy his friends:

> **SPOCK:** It is my right. By tradition, the male is accompanied by his **closest friends**.
>
> **KIRK:** Thank you, Mister Spock.

Spock calling Kirk his friend:

> **SPOCK:** He does not know. I will do what I must, T'Pau, but not with him! His blood does not burn. **He is my friend!**

Once again:

> **T'PAU:** Live long and prosper, Spock.
>
> **SPOCK:** I shall do neither. I have killed my captain and **my friend**. Energize.

[image]

Above, you can see Spock's relief upon finding Kirk alive.

Comment: Also worth mentioning is [Spock smiling at the end of Amok Time](http://www.letswatchstartrek.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/Picture-302.png) when he realized Kirk was not dead after all.

Comment: @Ixrec : Added --- thanks!

Comment: @lxrec: Merely his **logical** relief that Starfleet was spared the loss of such a talented officer....

Comment: On the other hand, smiling because you didn't actually murder someone isn't the greatest sign of _friendship_ toward that same non-murdered person.

Comment: @imallett He didn't so much *smile* as *shout* "*Jim! You're alive!*" with an accompanying change in body posture that all but screams with heartfelt giddy emotion. :)

Comment: @Lexible Okay (haven't seen TOS since undergrad, and the picture told me it was just a smile).  Still, _"Hey I didn't really murder you!  BFFs, yah?"_ is sortof weird evidence IMO.

Comment: @imallett It makes more sense in context. He was not entirely sane or in control of himself when he thought he killed Kirk, and the smile/exclamation being pictured is by far the most emotional he gets in the entire series iirc (Vulcans don't normally emote)

Comment: The thing that really impressed me about that scene was McCoy.  He's always bickering with Spock about his silly Vulcan emotionless logicalness, and here's the chance for the doc to really twist the knife when Spock's stoic facade completely shatters.  He could mercilessly tease Spock about being not so superior as he pretends to be, he could bring this up at any point in the future... but he doesn't.  He realizes that this is a really powerful moment for Spock, and he lets it be.  That, more than anything else, established for me that underneath all the bickering, *those two are friends too.*

Comment: @imallet - when you profess to be completely ruled by logic,and to have put all emotions to rest, yes, it IS a big deal and evidence of friendship.  He wouldn't be so pleased, let alone show it, unless he was.  It might not be that way for humans, like you and I, but we're not Vulcans or half-Vulcans. If say, you profess to not feel, one way or another about a person, an emotional reaction would be an indication that you actually do, right? If I say animals are animals, and who cares, then weep whenever I see a dead squirrel by the road, that would be an indication that maybe I do care.

Answer (score 0):

In The Naked Time when Spock is affected by the virus and basically has a bit of an emotional breakdown he tells Kirk about how he's meant to be as a Vulcan and that when he feels friendship for Kirk he is ashamed.

Thus, Spock feels a strong bond of friendship despite these emotions being culturally discouraged.

Comment: It would have taken you only a few seconds to google the title of the episode and use correct spelling and grammar. Downvoted for lack of effort. I know you can do better.

Comment: "I award you no points, and may God have mercy on your soul"

Answer (score 0):

One of my favorite episodes as an example of how powerful their friendship is, would be "And the Children Shall Lead."

After the kids mind rape Kirk and hijack the ship, he is seen on the turbolift with Spock, losing his mind over fear of losing the *Enterprise.*  While Spock maintains his monotone through most of it, you can tell by his choice of decorum throughout it all how concerned he is for his friend. First when he tries to get Kirk to calm himself he refers to him as "Captain". Then when that doesn't work he tries getting his attention by referring to him as "Kirk", his last name to maintain some sense of professional dignity.

Unfortunately when he moved to restrain Kirk, Kirk tried to strangle him at first provocation. This lead to Spock in turn emotionally going for the throat. Referring to him by his first name "Jim." in a somewhat pleading tone. This causes Kirk to realize with regret what he almost done and regain his sanity. The look on Kirk's face literally amounted to "Holy Sh*** I almost choked my friend." Later when he regains his control over his mental state and formulates a plan against the kids, he refers to Spock as "My Vulcan friend."

If that is not a clear example of their friendship I don't know what is.